# Improper encoding in Java Read/Write file

Tags: java, file, dom, encoding, read-write

I want to write to a csv file in UTF-8 in java

I am using `BufferedWriter out  = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("temp.csv"),Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder()));` after searching the internet

I am still getting illegal characters.

I want to write "Kürzlich" to my file and later on read and write again from the same file.
When I do so I get "KÃ¼rzlich"

How I am getting "Kürzlich": I am parsing a xml file using DOM.

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputStream openstream = url.openStream();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(openstream);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

and then I extract my string.

I do not care how it is shown on the screen. I want to compare the stuff I write in the file with another file which is converted perfectly.

Is it happening because of DOM structure? Is there a way around?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be writing UTF-8, but I don't see how you are reading UTF-8.  Most likely you are reading the default encoding.

Try wrapping the openstream with an InputStreamReader specifying the encoding you want.

I suggest you try this to show you can write and read UTF-8

```
String text = "Kürzlich";
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-8")));
pw.println(text);
pw.close();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test.txt"), "UTF-8"));
String line = br.readLine();
br.close();
System.out.println("Text is the same is " + (line.equals(text)));
```

prints

```
Text is the same is true
```

Comment: I am reading the same way BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(yourFile),Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()));
But it comes later on so should not have anyeffect. It does not even write properly

Comment: Are you sure you are reading UTF-8 correctly when you say it is not correct?  How about using the `in` to parse from instead of creating it when it's too late?

Comment: Assuming I do not read. That is step 2. Just writing to a file using the code mentioned I am not getting correct result.

Comment: How do you know it is not the correct result if you are not reading it?

Comment: I am doing an equals from the from source A and and this file.I tired it before writing to the file too.

I check what the file contains in VI (as it does not contain any system encoding) and it shows me illegal characters

Comment: So when you check, you are reading the file. And this tool you are using to read the file you know is using UTF-8, and not another encoding?

Comment: Yes!
I am using  'BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(FileName),Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder()));'